# Sass Source Map in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, source-maps, ruby-on-rails-5

Trying to figure out why I can’t get source maps working in Rails 5. Rails 5 uses Sass 3.4.2x, so it seems like it shouldn’t have the problem previous versions of Rails had.

I’ve added the following to `config/environments/development.rb`

```
# Enable source maps for Sass
config.sass.inline_source_maps = true
```

Answer (score -1):

In your `Gemfile`

**Remove**

`gem 'sass-rails'`

**Add**

`gem 'sassc-rails'`

**Enjoy Source Maps**